# Changing extension of multiple files in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: files, rename

As the title says, how can I change the extension of every file in a directory in Ubuntu? I've seen some examples use rename etc etc but I get an error (Unable to locate package rename) and it's not accessible through apt-get.

As an additional, I don't actually know the original file type! It's data that's been copied from the file system of Hadoop to the local drive and I need them all to be in .txt format.

If it makes a difference, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 in Oracle Virtual Box

**Edit: Output of:
ls -l /usr/bin/*rename* /etc/alternatives/rename**

```
amartin24@ubuntu-amartin24:~/TwitterMining/JSONTweets$ ls -l /usr/bin/*rename* /etc/alternatives/rename
ls: cannot access /etc/alternatives/rename: No such file or directory
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10392 Mar 30  2012 /usr/bin/rename.ul
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `cd` to the directory in question and execute something similar to this:

```
find -L . -type f -name "*.oldextension" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' FNAME; do
    mv -- "$FNAME" "${FNAME%.oldextension}.newextension"
done
```

Or if the files don't have any extension at all:

```
find -L . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' FNAME; do
    mv -- "$FNAME" "${FNAME%}.newextension"
done
```

In your case you would have to replace `newextension` with `txt`.

Someone more proficient with bash might be able to break this down better. Please feel free to edit my answer in that case.

---

Original description:

> 1) It will rename *just the file extension* (due to use of
>   `${FNAME%.so}.dylib`). All the other solutions using
>   `${X/.so/.dylib}` are incorrect as they wrongly rename *the
>   first occurrence* of `.so` in the filename (e.g.
>   `x.so.so` is renamed to `x.dylib.so`, or worse,
>   `./libraries/libTemp.so-1.9.3/libTemp.so` is renamed to
>   `./libraries/libTemp.dylib-1.9.3/libTemp.so` - an error).
>
> 2) It will handle spaces and any other special characters in filenames
>   (except double quotes).
>
> 3) It will not change directories or other special files.
>
> 4) It will follow symbolic links into subdirectories and links to
>   target files and rename the target file, not the link itself (the
>   default behaviour of find is to process the symbolic link itself, not
>   the file pointed to by the link).

Source:

[Bash rename extension recursive - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171966/bash-rename-extension-recursive), answered by [aps2012](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1357650/aps2012).

Comment: That's correct, but a lot more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: As I couldn't get rename working, I went with this. A little longer, but works perfectly. Thanks for putting the time into answering this.

Answer (score 5):

The `rename` command is already installed, you don't need to add anything else.

`rename` takes Perl code as its first argument. Most concrete use cases of renaming consist of a regexp replacement: `s/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/`. To remove the existing extension, replace everything starting at the last `.` character.

```
rename 's/\.[^.]*$/.txt/' /path/to/directory/*
```

If your files have no extension (no `.` in their name), you can either use `$` (which matches the end of the file name) as the regexp, or append `.txt` to the name.

```
rename '$_ = "$_.txt"'  /path/to/directory/*
```

This doesn't change the content of the files, it only renames them. If your data isn't in the format you want, that's a completely unrelated problem.

Comment: Didn't know about rename. This is definitely more elegant than my solution. +1

Comment: I'd love to use this solution, but when I run it it says "rename: command not found". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AndrewMartin That's really weird. Oh, that command is part of the `perl` package, which may no longer be installed by default on server installations. But even if `perl` isn't installed, you should have a `rename` command with a different syntax (that isn't as useful for this question) instead.

Comment: I tried installing perl, but apparently it's already installed. Do you have any other suggestions on how to get rename working?

Comment: @AndrewMartin Something's wrong with your system. What does `ls -l /usr/bin/*rename* /etc/alternatives/rename` show? What about `type rename perl` and `echo $PATH`?

Comment: The first option shows /usr/bin/rename.u1

Comment: The "type rename perl" says -bash: type: rename: not found, then: perl is /usr/bin/perl

Comment: Finally, echo $PATH just shows my path location, including the usr/bin folder

Comment: @AndrewMartin Copy-paste please. Do you really have a file called `/usr/bin/rename.u1`? and what about `/etc/alternatives/rename`? Also, what about `dpkg -L perl | grep rename`?

Comment: Nevermind, got it working. When I ran dpkg I saw that Perl location needed updating. I fixed that and then the command worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this simple bash script

rename_ext_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *
do
  mv -- "${file}" "${file%.*}.txt"
done
```

this script works for both cases with extension or without

Comment: Yeech, that's horrible. [Always put double quotes around command substitutions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). [Don't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Your script needlessly mangles file names containing whitespace or globbing characters.

Comment: you are right, but this one is for simple cases. once I faced with a similar problem

Comment: changed it for files with spaces

Comment: @lexeek If you just quoted your variables, you wouldn't need to bother with $IFS...

Comment: Why so complicated? And this still doesn't handle file names containing wildcard characters. See my edit.

Comment: I am sorry but I am just a newby with unix and bash :)in consequence of this that I'm on the forum.

Comment: If you're a newbie, you should definitely read through the wiki Gilles linked to, it is one of the best bash resources on the web.

Answer (score 1):

### GUI solution

---

**Overview**

There is a really easy to use and powerful GUI tool in the Ubuntu Software Center to rename batches of files, pyRenamer.

**Installation**

```
sudo apt-get install pyrenamer
```

or

[image: Foo]
<sub>(source: [ubuntu.com](https://apps.ubuntu.com/assets/images/scbutton-free-200px.png))</sub>

**Screenshots**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you walk us through on how you would use pyrename to change the extension of all files in a directory? I.e. what patterns would you use?

Comment: Thanks for this, but I should have specified that I can't use a GUI (accessing a remote VM without GUI available)

Answer (score 0):

I have this script. I know it is not dummy-prove, namely while handling files with spaces. That is why I run detox at the begining.

```
#!/bin/bash
#   detox * 
# uncomment if you want to get rid of spaces and funny characters
    script=$(basename $0)
if  [ -z "$1" ] || [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ]; then
    clear   
    echo "Script for adding an extension to files without extension"
    echo "---------------------------------------------------------"
    echo -e "\n Usage:"
    echo -e "   $script extension\n"
    echo -e "Exampli gratia: \n The command:"
    echo "      $script txt"
    echo -e "   will rename:\n      FileWithoutExtension -> FileWithoutExtension.txt\n"

else
for file in $(ls -p -I '*.*' | grep -v '/$') # excludes direcotires
    do 
    mv -iv "$file" "$file.$1"
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of files without extensions at all (like `./out_1`, `./out_2`, `out_3`, ... ) :

```
cd YOUR_DIRECTORY_HERE
ls | xargs -i{} mv {} {}.YOUR_EXTENSION_HERE
```

example

```
ls | xargs -i{} mv {} {}.md
```