# How to rename various file extension into an extension

Tags: bash, files, extension, rename

I have many files in a directory with various extension (files.txt, files.html, files.jpg, etc). I need to change all the extension of these files into an extension (files.ext.backup). So, I will change:

*.txt ==> *.txt.backup

*.jpg ==> *.jpg.backup

and so on.

I realized that I need to change the extension of each type, but at least I don't have to change them one by one. How should I do that ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and give more details and/or an example on what you are trying to accomplish. As it is currently written, it's hard to know what your exact question really is.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/333026/changing-extension-of-multiple-files-in-ubuntu-12-04 and also have a look at the "rename" command (it accepts regexes).